# What percentage of US households had electricity and telephones in 1940?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, technology, electricity

I'm trying to find a published source giving the percent of U.S. households having electricity and percent having telephones in 1940 (+/- a year or two). Not interested in the rural vs city divide per se, but, rather, the aggregate stats.

The numbers don't need to be super accurate either -- I'm happy to read off of a graph.

I've poked around the internet, and, to my surprise, couldn't find these stats very easily. I also have Julie Cohn "The Grid", but the numbers (for electrification) are not readily found there either.

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you looked already (to avoid duplication of effort)?

Comment: This is earlier than the timeframe you are looking for, but at least one data point. [National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/edis/learn/kidsyouth/the-electric-light-system-phonograph-motion-pictures.htm): "Only in 1925 did half of all homes in the U.S. have electric power."

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrification): " ... about 1930 when 70% of households were electrified in the U.S."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Citing a U.S. Census Bureau publication, "Historical Statistics of the United States, Colonial Times to 1970," [this website](https://www.richmondfed.org/publications/research/econ_focus/2020/q1/economic_history) of the Federal Reserve Bank of Richmond shows a graph indicating that in 1940, 85% of all US residences had access to electricity.

[Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/189959/housing-units-with-telephones-in-the-united-states-since-1920/), crediting their own research department, provides a bar graph that indicates that in 1940 36.9% of all US housing units had a telephone. [This site](https://transportgeography.org/contents/chapter1/the-setting-of-global-transportation-systems/household-telecommunications-united-states/) shows a graph based on US government sources confirming that number. The site owner requests that it be cited as: Rodrigue, J-P et al. (2020) The Geography of Transport Systems, Hofstra University, Department of Global Studies & Geography, https://transportgeography.org.

Comment: I appreciate the Federal Reserve Bank source for electrification. That is good enough for me. The Statista site for telephones possibly cites sources, but they are behind a pay wall. So I think I'm half way there with this. Thank you.

Comment: I will look at this tomorrow. Sorry. Busy at the moment, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: njuffa, this is all excellent. I will use this in my project. I am very happy that you were able to dig this up. Thank you.